# How do I give permissions to allow SickRage access to a USB drive?

Tags: usb, mount, permissions, fstab

I retired my ancient RAID and I'm trying to replace it with a USB external drive. It is mounted and all of the files are there, but when I'm in the [SickRage](https://sickrage.github.io) **Add Shows > Add Existing Shows** it will navigate to the mount point of the drive `/media/niceraid` (so I can see the next level of sub-directories) but it won't traverse down the tree any further. There are no errors in the SickRage logs and I don't see anything in syslog or auth.log that would indicate an issue.

My guess is this is related to the permissions for "sickrage:sickrage" -- created per instructions at the [SickRage github](https://github.com/SickRage/SickRage/wiki/Sickrage-installation-Debian-Ubuntu-14-15-16).

Here are some things that might be helpful for troubleshooting.

```
$ lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME                  FSTYPE        SIZE MOUNTPOINT      LABEL
sdb                                 1.8T                 
└─sdb1                ext4          1.8T /media/niceraid ext4test
sr0                   iso9660      24.1M                 DRIVER
sda                               232.9G                 
├─sda2                                1K                 
├─sda5                LVM2_member 232.4G                 
│ ├─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 swap            8G [SWAP]          
│ └─ubuntu--vg-root   ext4        224.4G /               
└─sda1                ext2          487M /boot           

$ more /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5). 
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=69002371-b4e7-4c0b-95ec-ca5b7099a4d6 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
# hope to mount USB drive with media for server at boot
UUID=5b15a6ab-7b25-4f56-a2f3-0fe3878d2246 /media/niceraid ext4 user,umask=000,utf8,flush,noauto 0 0

$ sudo blkid /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="ext4test" UUID="5b15a6ab-7b25-4f56-a2f3-0fe3878d2246" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="9cdd1ee1-01"

$ ll /media/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   4 root     root     4096 Jun  1 21:26 ./
drwxr-xr-x  24 root     root     4096 Jun  1 22:46 ../
drwxr-x---+  3 root     root     4096 Jun  1 22:47 jaireaux/
drwxrw-rw-   8 jaireaux jaireaux 4096 Jun  1 13:13 niceraid/

$ ll /media/niceraid/
total 81964
drwxrw-rw-  8 jaireaux jaireaux     4096 Jun  1 13:13 ./
drwxr-xr-x  4 root     root         4096 Jun  1 21:26 ../
drwxrw-rw-  3 jaireaux jaireaux     4096 Jun  1 13:13 audio/
drwxrw-rw-  2 root     root        16384 Jun  1 13:10 lost+found/
drwxrw-rw-  5 jaireaux jaireaux     4096 Jun  1 13:13 other/
drwxrw-rw-  2 jaireaux jaireaux     4096 Jun  1 13:13 temporary/
-rw-rw-rw-  1 jaireaux jaireaux 83886080 Jun  1 13:10 tmp.output
drwxrw-rw- 10 jaireaux jaireaux     4096 Jun  1 13:13 downloads/
drwxrw-rw-  6 jaireaux jaireaux     4096 Jun  1 13:13 videos/

$ ll /media/niceraid/videos/
total 28
drwxrw-rw-  6 jaireaux jaireaux 4096 Jun  1 13:13 ./
drwxrw-rw-  8 jaireaux jaireaux 4096 Jun  1 13:13 ../
drwxrw-rw-  2 jaireaux jaireaux 4096 Jun  1 13:13 other1/
drwxrw-rw- 57 jaireaux jaireaux 4096 Jun  1 13:16 movie/
drwxrw-rw-  2 jaireaux jaireaux 4096 Jun  1 13:13 other2/
drwxrw-rw- 95 jaireaux jaireaux 4096 Jun  1 19:50 television/
-rwxrw-rw-  1 jaireaux jaireaux   11 Jun  1 13:13 temp.txt*
```

What else should I look at?

Answer (score 0):

Looking through [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332731/permission-denied-dev-bus-usb), I see that users need execute permissions for some types of access. Maybe someone could flush out the details further, but this fixed my problem.

```
sudo chmod -R a+x /media/niceraid
```